# How to handle special character hyphen in request body in loadrunner

Tags: json, api, http, automated-tests, loadrunner

I am getting a 400 bad request when I try to post a request using loadrunner.
This is a json request.
Sample body

{
Tester : Batman - superman

}

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's not well-formed JSON. Try putting the strings into double quotes.